# How to put a warning disable pragma inside a macro gcc

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, pragma

I need to disable a warning that originates inside the macro '__LOG_W' in following code. To do that, I wrapped this macro inside another macro 'LOG_W' and disabled the warning '-Wold-style-cast' with in that. Then in the code I used the LOG_W instead. 
However I still get the warning and unable to find out why. Any pointers appreciated.

```
#define LOG_W(expr)\
  _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push")\
  _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wold-style-cast\"")\
  __LOG_W(DEF, UNKNOWN, expr);\
  _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")
```

Comment: Are you sure the parameters passed to `_Pragma` are supported by your version of GCC? I don't believe the compiler is required to issue a warning if it does not recognize the arguments.

Comment: yes, and if I do the samethig outside of the macro, it works.

Comment: Possibly a manifestation of https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431 ?

Comment: Not working for me too. Seems like GCC bug.